# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. (webapi2:80)

Tags: c#, windows, docker-compose, httprequest, .net-8.0

when i tring to make get request from webapi1 to webapi2 i get an error

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. (webapi2:80)

webapi1 and webapi2 inside docker

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapi1:
    container_name: webapi1  
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapi1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApi1\Dockerfile
    environment:
       - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
       - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

    ports:
       - "6001:80"
       - "6002:443"
 
  webapi2:
    container_name: webapi2 
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapi2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApi2\Dockerfile
    environment:
       - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80;        
       - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

    ports:
      - "7001:80"
      - "7002:443"
```

the call in webapi1

```
httpClient.GetAsync($"http://webapi2/home/get")
```

when i replace the webapi2 with the ip the docker generate, the call works but with webapi2 i get an error , its worked before for couple of minutes i dont know what has cahnged

Containers

```
  "Containers": {
            "7562b06fd77915b0e09c8edb4128d4b6970f9511dd7a5e8363b43443633001d9": {
                "Name": "webapi1",
                "EndpointID": "71e9445f1a412c195e9e4a197fef6e69a90c83baeb833a7ccbf1a9632bee3e4d",
                "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:c1:16:18",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.67.34/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "86f3e842c758ca2af5785d8fea719c625ed70897274563377fca63fa389d344a": {
                "Name": "webapi2",
                "EndpointID": "470e61940bbd95ca1303fded630ce000e0b5d2b47cfac1afbe859785a6432e58",
                "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:c1:1d:fb",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.76.208/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```